# Is there a way to use angular material autocomplete to autocomplete objects with array of objects that has an id of type number?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, numeric, mat-autocomplete

Assume that the object array,

```
books = [{id:1, name: 'book1'}, {id:2, name: 'book2'}];
```

Here you can see that the *id* of each element in the array is a number. Angular autocomplete component does not work when the array of objects is in the given format.
Any workarounds?
How can I use the *id* of the book to autocomplete?

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, you just have to convert the `id` to a string before you filter.

> Working stackblitz is
>   [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-kojajh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).
>   Example is based on the Angular Material documentation from
>   [here](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples).

I made two changes to the example to make it work so you can filter by the `id`.

First of in the `ngOnInit` I made sure to use the `id` attribute of the `Book` object to pass to the `_filter` function.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith<string | Book>(''),
      map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.id),
      map(id => id ? this._filter(id) : this.options.slice())
    );
}
```

And in the `_filter` function itself just convert the `id` to a string.

```
private _filter(id: number | string): Book[] {
  const filterValue = String(id);
  return this.options.filter(option => String(option.id).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to simply transform the user input into a number and perform the equality check against the raw int values, instead of transforming everything to string on every value change?

Comment: Yes I agree, that would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: The autocomplete on the StackBlitz does not work.  If you start typing all the options go away.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to just create a angular pipe to filter the data you want. You will be able to keep the filtering in one place, rather than create ever more TS code. The above solution you will have to do for every control, and if you have a lot of auto-completes on the page will get messy.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterac'
})
export class FilterACPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], ...args: any[]): any[] {
    if (args[0] && args[0].length) {
      value = value.filter(nextVal => {
        // Add lowercase, or can work on more complex objects.
        return (nextVal.indexOf(args[0]) > -1);
      });
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

And then in the HTML:

```
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of dataArray | filterac : myControl.value" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
```